# How to output videos over 1920 pixels wide in Handbrake?

Tags: video, resolution, encoding, handbrake

I have rendered a raw AVI from a 3D software that is in the cinemascope 2048 x 858 pixels resolution.

Handbrake CAN output that size in the end result using anamorphic distortion, but if I turn anamorphic to OFF, it doesn't let me set the ACTUAL output resolution to the same as source, because it doesn't allow me to go beyond 1920 pixels wide.

Is this a hard cap or am I missing some other setting?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your source is 2048 pixels *wide* by 858 *high*, but you keep mentioning  *height* as the  thing you want to increase beyond 1920. Are you sure you are changing the right option? Is this just a typo in your question?

Comment: Wow, I'm sorry that totally slipped my mind... dear god. XD
Totally my mistake. Will edit to fix that. thanks for the catch!
Also to note, even the height of 858 pixels can't be increased once my width is set to 1920. I never noticed because I didn't try to increase the height, since it's at the perfect number. But THIS is likely happening because to go higher would be upscaling.